# Scheme with Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Can Broadcast Receiver listen for scheme? Example for Activity.

```
<intent-filter >
   <data android:scheme="http"/>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

EDIT:
The company is using it's own protocol .. so it's not http in scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could just use that same `<intent-filter>` element inside of your `<receiver>` (instead of `<activity>`).

Comment: The `action` and `category` have to correspond to a valid broadcast intent, of course.

Comment: I did and it's not working as opposite to Activity which is fine if i add the same code. With broadcast receiver it gives me in logcat "protocol is not supported" - something like that.

Comment: What `action` and `category` are you specifying in the intent filter?

Comment: You cannot use a broadcast receiver for the android.intent.action.VIEW action, because that intent is sent using `startActivity(...)` instead of `sendBroadcast(...)`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21418/discussion-between-tommy-and-tomi-s)

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, here is a simple working example:

Send a broadcast as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("my.custom.action");
intent.setData(Uri.parse("myapp://apphost/"));
context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

In your manifest, register a broadcast receiver with the following intent filter.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="my.custom.action"/>
    <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="apphost"/>
</intent-filter>
```